# How to handle asynchronous operations with rusty_v8

Tags: rust, runtime, v8, deno

I'm trying to develop a simple js runtime on top of v8 (rusty_v8) and I'm having some trouble with async stuff.

I have a function that is an entry point from the js realm:

```rust
fn message_from_worker(
    scope: &mut v8::HandleScope,
    args: v8::FunctionCallbackArguments,
    _ret: v8::ReturnValue,
)

// ...
```

This function takes different kinds of messages from the js realm and does different things with them. One of the messages is a request to do a long running task (fetch). I want to be able to send a message back to the js realm when the task is done.

So far this is what I have:

```rust
fn message_from_worker ... {

  // ...
    let message = args.get(0);
    let message = message.to_object(scope).unwrap();

    let kind = utils::get(scope, message, "kind").to_rust_string_lossy(scope);

    match kind.as_str() {
        // ...
        "fetch" => {
            let request = utils::get(scope, message, "request");
            let request = request.to_object(scope).unwrap();
  
            let url = utils::get(scope, request, "url").to_rust_string_lossy(scope);

            let callback = utils::get(scope, message, "sendResponse");
            let callback = match v8::Local::<v8::Function>::try_from(callback) {
                Ok(callback) => callback,
                Err(_) => {
                    utils::throw_type_error(scope, "sendResponse is not a function");
                    return;
                }
            };

            // We want to perform our async http request here

            let response = { /* for now response is a sync mock */ };

            let undefined = v8::undefined(scope).into();

            callback.call(scope, undefined, &[response.into()]);
        }

        // ...
```

The naive approach (using a blocking request) doesn't work:

```rust
reqwest::blocking::get(&url).unwrap()
```

`Cannot drop a runtime in a context where blocking is not allowed. This happens when a runtime is dropped from within an asynchronous context.`

---

So I'm thinking about registering all pending operations in a global state and then poll them from the main thread. I'm not sure how to do this though.

I don't even know if I can poll multiple operations at the same time, handling the resolution of one of them and then continue to poll the rest.

---

EDIT: I [published the source code](https://github.com/max-lt/test-js-runtime/tree/fetch) to make it easier to reproduce, the current code is on the `fetch` branch, use `cargo run --bin cli scripts/fetch.js --event=fetch` to execute de fetch script and trigger the fetch event